# ¿Cómo podemos gestionar los enlaces del DLE que van cambiando constantemente de formato?

Tags: discusión, petición-de-funcionalidad, estado-completado, formato, enlaces

Si por ejemplo busco [publicaciones mías de 2015 o antes](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1674%20created%3A..2015%20rae), veo que el formato de entradas del DLE solía ser del tipo:

- `http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=X` ejemplo: http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=electroencefalografista, [funcionó una temporada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/3943/1674), o bien
- `http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=X`, ejemplo: http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=fI2tR6J3xDXX2xbjCXW9

Ambos tipos ya no funcionan y, por tanto, los enlaces están rotos.

Los que sí funcionan son del tipo:

- `http://dle.rae.es/?id=17iDZMe` (redirige a `https://dle.rae.es/agradar`)

Si bien actualmente (enero 2020) al buscar en el DLE nos devuelve resultados del tipo:

- `https://dle.rae.es/?w=X`, por ejemplo https://dle.rae.es/?w=agradar

Si miramos en el Data Explorer, vemos que:

- [864 publicaciones](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/1179394/lema-rae) contienen el texto `lema.rae.es`.
- [252 publicaciones](https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/1179394/lema-rae-drae) contienen el texto `lema.rae.es/drae/`, que es el potencialmente cambiable.

Cambiar uno a uno los enlaces sería una auténtica pesadilla, pero Stack Exchange como empresa a veces hace estas actualizaciones masivas ([ejemplo reciente](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12715) o [uno más famoso y antiguo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237110/209901)). Cada enlace que no funciona es una pena (¡y nos recuerda que hay que copiar el contenido relevante por si eso pasa!), por lo que planteo dos cosas:

- [discusión](/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n) ¿Deberíamos tener alguna página entremedia para los enlaces al DLE, de manera que pudiéramos mapear de esa a la versión correspondiente del DLE sin tener que modificar una a una todas las publicaciones cada vez que cambia el formato?
- [petición-de-funcionalidad](/questions/tagged/petici%c3%b3n-de-funcionalidad) Una vez hecho eso: ¿podría Stack Exchange como empresa actualizar los enlaces de forma masiva?

Comment: ¿Cómo sería esa página intermedia? ¿Sería necesario que cada vez que escribimos una respuesta añadiéramos una entrada a esa página y que cada vez que leemos una respuesta tuviéramos que pinchar en dos enlaces seguidos en lugar de uno?

Comment: @wimi mi pensamiento inicial es hacer algo así como un redireccionador para hacerlo automáticamente, de manera que si dijéramos p ej redirigerae.com/hola él solito buscara cada vez el artículo correspondiente a "hola" en el DLE. Por tanto, la única tarea sería ir cambiando la redirección interna por la versión del DLE del momento. Técnicamente es superfácil, pero no sé en qué medida la comunidad podría aceptar usar siempre ese vínculo entremedio... ¿No sería fantástico tener un "añadidor de enlaces al DLE" como snippet en el botón de edición que hiciera todo esto?

Comment: There only seem to be 50+ with lema.rae.es and I would be happy to edit them over the next few weeks. Even at two or three a day it will not flood the front page.

Comment: @mdewey I checked with data.SE and there are 252 right now! I updated the question with the link to the query, which is https://data.stackexchange.com/spanish/query/1179394/lema-rae-drae

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

A día 26 de febrero de 2020, los enlaces se han corregido gracias a la inestimable ayuda de [Juan M](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/users/9214/juan-m).

---

Por dejarlo reflejado como respuesta, para que pueda ser votada:

- Si cambiamos `http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=X` por `https://dle.rae.es/X`, funciona correctamente. Nótese que si X no contiene caracteres especiales, la redirección ya la hace automáticamente la web de la RAE. Si los contiene, da problemas.
- Si cambiamos `http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=X` por `https://dle.rae.es/?id=X`, eso no redirige a la definición correcta, sino a la página principal del diccionario. Esto es porque esas búsquedas corresponden a la versión de 2001 del diccionario, por lo que habría que redirigirlas a `http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=X`. Si os fijáis es simplemente cambiar `drae` por `drae2001`.

Dado que tenemos los dos cambios necesarios, podríamos solicitar a los CMs su sustitución automática. Teniendo en cuenta que hay cientos de cambios pendientes, no sé cuánto nos llevaría hacerlo a mano, si más o menos que los más de tres meses que tardaron los CMs en el [ejemplo reciente](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12715) que has enlazado. Tal vez sea mejor avisar publicando un post en Meta y que lo arreglen cuando puedan, nos ahorraría mucho esfuerzo.

Lo que no termino de ver es lo de meter un servidor de redirección. Eso supondría cambiar todos los enlaces al DLE que hay actualmente en todo el sitio, y no solo eso, sino también educar a todos los futuros usuarios para que usen dicho servidor en sus publicaciones.

Comment: La parte de educar a los usuarios es la que me ha convencido. No veo una forma sencilla de evitar que se sigan usando enlaces directos a la web del DLE, y no solo por parte de usuarios nuevos (somos animales de costumbres).

Comment: @Charlie Necesitamos un poco de clarificación con la sintaxis de la corrección del segundo punto. La respuesta sugiere que cambiemos el URL a http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?val=fI2tR6J3xDXX2xbjCXW9 pero eso nos esta dando un error.

Comment: @JuanM no sé cómo lo hice el otro día, pero tienes razón, el enlace correcto es [con "id" en vez de con "val"](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=fI2tR6J3xDXX2xbjCXW9). Las búsquedas por "id" son por el identificador de la palabra, y por "val" son por la palabra exacta. Así que bastaría con cambiar "drae" por "drae2001". Eso funciona en casi todos los ejemplos que he probado (alguno ha fallado, no sé por qué, pero mejor tener casi todos los enlaces arreglado a ninguno arreglado). He actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: @Charlie ¡Gracias! Intentaremos de nuevo. :)

Comment: @Charlie Hemos renovado las URLs y parece que se ha corregido todo. Por favor alértame si vez algo por ahí que este mal.

Comment: @JuanM ¡Muchas gracias por la ayuda! ¡Así lo haré!

Comment: ¡¡¡Gran noticia @JuanM y Charlie!!! Muchas gracias por vuestros esfuerzos

Comment: Veo que se han modificado como 240 publicaciones, pues aparece en el [historial de revisiones del usuario Community](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=all&page=13)

Answer (score 1):

Tener una página intermedia que redirija automáticamente a la dirección correcta de la RAE es una buena idea. No nos costaría nada escribir en nuestras respuestas algo como `redirigerae.com/hola` en lugar de `dle.rae.es/hola`. Como dice fedorqui en los comentarios, técnicamente es fácil de implementar y mantener, pero entiendo que hace falta un sitio donde *host* (albergar?) esa página de redirección. No sé si Stack Exchange ofrece esa posibilidad, quizá esto también es una [petición-de-funcionalidad](/questions/tagged/petici%c3%b3n-de-funcionalidad).

Tiene que ser fácil de usar y mantener: no creo que una solución que requiriera añadir cada palabra manualmente a la página intermedia funcionara bien.

Por supuesto, estoy completamente de acuerdo con la segunda [petición-de-funcionalidad](/questions/tagged/petici%c3%b3n-de-funcionalidad) de cambiar los enlaces rotos.

Comment: [se] cambió todos los enlaces rotos! Véase la respuesta de Charlie